# AnagularJS Component - UI-roter - parent child comunication

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have problem with setting comunication between AngularJS Components with ui-router.

Here is an UI-router configuration example:

```js
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<parent-component></parent-component>'
})
.state('parent.child', {
    url: "/child-a/",
    template: '<child-component></child-component>'
})
```

What I need to solve is passing some variables from parent component to child component...

In simple template it is easy to make parent child comunication

```
   <div>
        <child-component some-variable="$ctrl.variable"></child-component>
   <div>
```

But what is solution for comunnication using UI-router?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With ui-router you can use either the `resolve` or the `data` properties of the state definition to pass data between the parent and child: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states

You can also create a Service that is injected into both states that will store the shared information.